# Bound Service invocation gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, service

Hi and thanks for your help.

I have the following activity (see code below). The activities bounds (or tries to bound) to a Service.

The service exposes (or it should expose) a public method getNumber() to retrieve a number.

When the execution gets to

```
 mService.getNumber()
```

the app stops returning a NullPointerException.

I debugged and all I can understand is that for for some reason the mService.getNumber() causes the problem.

EDIT: APPARENTLY THE SERVICE DOES NOT BIND, I tested the mBound boolean after the

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and it returns false, therefore the Service does not bind... the problem is there!

Thanks for any suggestion

```
 public class Quotes extends Activity {
    public LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
             // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.e("", "arrivo a prima di loop");
        for(int a=0;;a++){
            SystemClock.sleep(500); 
            Log.e("", "sono nel loop");
            int num =mService.getNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(num),     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }
       private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            //@Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                Log.e("", "sono in ServiceConnection");
    // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get    LocalService instance
                LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
            }
            //@Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };
```

This is code of the Service:

```
package com.example.quotes;

@TargetApi(3)
public class LocalService extends Service {
    public int i;
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
              * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
      * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
      */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("", "sono nel service");
         new Task().execute();
        return mBinder;
    } 
         class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
         @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        for (i=0;;i++) {
        Log.e("Sono nel AsyncTask del Service", Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
        }
        //return(null);
        }
     }

    public int getNumber() {
        return i;
    }       
 }
```

LogCat:

```
12-21 12:05:18.837: D/AndroidRuntime(889): Shutting down VM
12-21 12:05:18.837: W/dalvikvm(889): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40a13300)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quotes/com.example.quotes.Quotes}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.example.quotes.Quotes.onCreate(Quotes.java:91)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-21 12:05:18.887: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what it is for(int a=0;;a++)

Comment: use Intent intent = new Intent(currentClassName, LocalService.class);

Comment: you should indeed copy your Logcat error trace in here. Also nullify your mService on the onServiceDisconnected() method with mService = null;

Comment: @Cobra it is an infinite loop, for testing puropses

Comment: @Cobra used you suggestion without success

Comment: @PeterGriffin I did as you suggested, no relults.

Comment: Wasn't supposed to fix it ^^ Last time I used a bound service I had a similar problem : I was trying to use the service to quickly. Try to start your loop out of the onCreate() method (like add a Button and on its listener start the loop). Declare your mService as private instead of public as well in the Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, foud the solution to the riddle.

Binding to service is asynchronous.

The service is bound for sure only when onServiceConnected is called; therefore in onServiceConnected I add call a method that starts the activity that need to be performed on the Service.

Ciao